# What is the difference between spatial heterogeneity and spatial nonstationarity?

Tags: spatial-statistics, geographically-weighted-regression

Until recently I though both terms refer to the same concept. Most scientific literature seems to use these terms also interchangibly.

However, [here](https://gdsl-ul.github.io/san/geographically-weighted-regression.html#recap-spatial-effects) the authors say:

> Spatial heterogeneity refers to the uneven distribution of a variable’s values across space
>
> Spatial nonstationarity refers to variations in the relationship between an outcome variable and a set of predictor variables across space

So, who is right? Is there a difference between spatial heterogeneity and spatial nonstationarity? Is spatial nonstationarity a special case of spatial heterogeneity?